# Saleae Logic Analyser not working with SPI Receive

Tags: c, stm32, accelerometer, spi, stm32f4discovery

I am using the STM32F5 Discovery board to connect with an accelerometer using a breadboard. I connect the Saleae Logic Analyser to the bread board to the MISO, MOSI, CS, VCC, CLK and ground of the sensor.

First I try monitoring the SPI Transmit function only. It is successful and I am able to see the response. Now when I add a new line of code of SPI Receive to the existing code, I am unable to see anything on the logic analyser. I tried checking the status of the SPI Received variable in the KEIL watch window, and nothing is appearing.

Now when I disconnect the Logic Analyser and if I observe the data from the watch window, it is working fine.

I think there is some interfence between the logic analyser hardware and the Discovery Board/Sensor Hardware.

Has anyone else faced a similar situation earlier? Please let me know the solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No code, no wiring diagram >> WAG  It sounds like the logic analyzer is holding one of the data lines to ground

Comment: when you disconnected the logic analyzer, are you saying that communication works in both directions?  Are you familiar with the complete protocol for SPI, including the master has to request the data from the slave?

Comment: Yes, after disconnecting the logic analyser, the communication is working in both directions.